# sed + replace if one word in line and only other word not in line

Tags: linux, sed

I want to add the string crashkernel=100M on each ending line that begin with kernel word

but it will add the crashkernel=100M  only if line line not include the “crashkernel=” word

I write the following but this syntax isn’t works as expected

```
  sed  "/^#/b;  /kernel/  ;  /crashkernel=/!  s/$/ crashkernel=100M"  /etc/grub.conf
```

Comment: Please include examples of typical input and the desired output.

Comment: the examples of lines are from /etc/grub.conf file ( like centos OS )

Comment: or any other linux OS ,

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces to combine complex addresses.  The following should do what the OP intended to do, (assuming the OP's *substitute* code was accurate):

```
sed  '/^#/{/kernel/{/crashkernel=/!  s/$/ crashkernel=100M/}}'  /etc/grub.conf
```

Comment: While this snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.